# Ionic 3 keyboard plugin not working

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, angular6

I have a chat app which shows the user the keyboard when they tap the input.

Using Ionic's documentation I have added the onKeyboardShow() observer to my ts file. However it will not fire, no matter where i place it. The keyboard can be shown and hid over and over and nothing is ever fired.

```
import { Keyboard } from '@ionic-native/keyboard'; 

this.keyboard.onKeyboardShow()
      .subscribe(show => {
      console.log('Keyboard Up');
      this.scrollToBottom();
    })
```

It never prints to the console.

Comment: And you're injecting the keyboard through the constructor?

Comment: Nope, solved it though. the Ionic native plugin doesnt work, however the ionic angular keyboard works - willShow observer.